# Google Chrome showing some YouTube videos as restricted

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I started to face this issue lately version `76.0.3809.100`, when I'm browsing YouTube on Windows 7 Chrome, some videos won't open because they are restricted. Video is blacked-out saying

```
Video unavailable
This video is restricted. Try signing in with a Google Apps account.
```

While when I open the same video on Firefox with my account logged-in, I have no problem. Here is what I tried:

1. Chrome's Incognito is having the same issue.
2. Cleared Chrome's cache.
3. Removed Chrome completely using Your Uninstaller!
4. Tried a suggestion [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/11506284?hl=en) by modifying some Chrome flags but it didn't work.

I'm starting to conclude that it is a problem with Chrome itself, although I did not try other operating systems. What could be the problem?

Comment: No, I am logged-in on chrome. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some search on Chrome support forums, I found the same issue [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5509483?hl=en), [resetting chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en-GB) did the trick.